# Replace null values using key column in power query/power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

My question concerns power query editor of Excel and Power BI as well.
is there a way to replace the null values and fill down/up the cells in with the value from the column?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N1TF.png)

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the column and any of the option up or down to fill as shown in the below image.

[image]

Find more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fill-values-column

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"KEY"}, {{"data", each  Table.FillUp(Table.FillDown(_,{"Quantity", "variable"}),{"Quantity", "variable"}), type table   }}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"KEY"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", List,List),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Data",Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"cost", type number}, {"fixed", type number}, {"KEY", type number}, {"Quantity", type number}, {"variable", type number}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i know that there is an option for fill up/down, but this is not helpful in this situation as there is null for several key values. I need to fill based on the Key column